# handling models in laravel 5 like in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, laravel-5

I'm new on laravel.

I have functions on my model php. I want to use them in controller and send to view.

This is my example function.

```
public function select()
{
    $users = DB::table('user')->get();
}
```

now I need to use this on controller and view.

In codeigniter I handle it like this:

```
$data['content'] = $this->model->select();        
$this->load->view('admin/users', $data);
```

in codeigniter we first load model then we call its one of its method and then we pass processed data to view . what is counter part of this in laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 you can do it only using `controller`, like this:

```
public function select()
{
    $users = DB::table('user')->get();
    return view('admin.users',compact('users'));
}
```

if you want do it using Eloquent Model you need a model first. I assume you model name is `User` and your table name is `users`

**User.php**

```
protected $table = 'users'; // mention the table name
```

**UserController.PHP**

```
public function select()
{
    $users = User::all(); // it will return a collection of data form User model
    return view('admin.users',compact('users')); // write all variables you want pass through inside compact separated with comma
}
```